# How to select/highlight table row and "check" the checkbox (in the same table row) after filling (or clicking on) the input field in that same row?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to select/highlight table row and "check" the checkbox (in the same table row) after filling (or clicking on) the input field in that same row? I am using bootstrap table with jQuery. So each row that has filled some input field should be selected/highlighted and the checkbox in first column needs to be 'checked' for that row.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO please include in your question enough code to replicate your issue, At least the HTML markup for your table and the attempted Jquery code will be fine